# How is the oxidation number related to the group number?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, periodic-trends, oxidation-state

> If an element $\ce{X}$ forms the highest oxide of the formula $\ce{XO3}$, then it belongs to group:
>   **A**) 14
>   **B**) 15
>   **C**) 16
>   **D**) 17

How is an oxidation number of an element related to its group?

I tried comparing $\ce{X}$ with $\ce{N}$-, $\ce{S}$-, $\ce{As}$-compounds, but all 3 come in the form $\ce{XO3}$ ($\ce{NO3}$, $\ce{SO3}$, $\ce{AsO3}$), so I can't guess the group number.

Comment: Read the text more carefully. It says that the "highest oxide" has the formula $\ce{XO_3}$, while the 3 possibilities you mention contain only one oxide and 2 oxyanions.

Comment: Isn't $\ce{SO3}$ the highest oxide of $\ce{S}$?

Comment: actually SO4- is the highest oxide. Oxide means that the oxygen is more electronegative, not necessarily that the compound is also neutral.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For main group elements (groups 1, 2, 13-18), the highest possible oxidation state $O_\text{max}$ is given by the group number $G$ (for groups 1 and 2) or by the group number - 10 (for the rest):
$$ O_\text{max} = \begin{cases} G &\text{if } G \in \{1,2\} \\
G - 10 &\text{if } 13 \leq G \leq 18 \end{cases} $$

This means that for your compound $\ce{\stackrel{VI}{X}O3}$, so with the oxidation state VI, the corresponding group would be group 16.